# StrongLoop API Explorer not showing API

Tags: strongloop

I am brand new to StrongLoop Arc and tried simply setting up a Data Source (a mysql database) and then had it derive the Model from that Data Source.  I started the AppController running using the button on the Arc gui and then accessed the `localhost:3000/explorer` url to look at the generated api.  Unfortunately, I just get the message:

```
fetching resource list: http://localhost:3000/explorer/swagger.json
```

in the browser (Safari on OS X).  If I bring up the browser's error console I see:

```
TypeError: Swagger 2.0 does not support null types([object Object]).
```

Can anyone provide some insight into what might be going wrong?  I see at the top of the browser that the Token is not set.  Does this need to somehow be set before I can see anything?

Comment: Are you following this tutorial https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIS/Composing+APIs  ??

Comment: Yes, I believe that that was the tutorial I was using.  As it turns out, the problem was that there were some fields in the json generated by strongloop that had values of 'null' which one of the packages did not like.  Deleting those items with values of null after the json was generated fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that there were some fields in the json generated by strongloop that had values of 'null' which one of the packages did not like. Deleting those items with values of null after the json was generated fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZUeV.png)
  `"properties": {
    "seller": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": true,
      "default": "{}"`

delete this line or  modify like this (ps:I wrote before "default":null )

Answer (score 0):

This arises due to following reasons:

- There is `null` value corresponding to a key in you Model definition file. Delete the `null` value.
- Mistyping of fixed value attributes like `type`, `min`, `max`
  Eg. instead of `{ "type": "string" }` you are using `{ "type": "String" }`